# No Matching Function To Call Error, and i don't know why

Tags: c++, function

I'm having an error that the function that I'm calling doesn't exist and I don't know why. It seems to have something to do with pointers but we haven't learned pointers. I call the function and wrote it and declared it (I'm mostly just typing so I can post this at this point)

Here is my code

```
/*
 * Program to validate a color and show its index
 *
 * Name:    Rebecca Sakson
 * Date:    November 13, 2022
 */

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int NUM_COLORS = 5;

int findColorIndex (string findMe, string list[], int index[]);

int main()
{
    string colors[NUM_COLORS] = { "red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "purple"};
    int index[NUM_COLORS] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    string findMe;
    int colorIndex;
    //int idkWhy = NUM_COLORS;

    cout << "Color?" << endl;
    cin >> findMe;

    colorIndex = findColorIndex(findMe, colors, NUM_COLORS);
    if (colorIndex <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Color is valid, found at " << colorIndex << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << findMe << " is not valid";
    }
    
    return 0;
}

int findColorIndex (string findColor, string list[], int index[])
{
    bool found = false;
    int functionIndex = 0;

    while ((!found) && (functionIndex < *index))
    {
        if (list[functionIndex] == findColor)
        {
            found = true;
        }
        else
        {
            functionIndex++;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        functionIndex = -1;
    }

    return functionIndex;
}
```

Comment: Fyi, include `<string>`. It's required if you're using `std::string`. Don't assume some other header sucks it in for you.  Regarding your problem, perhaps `findColorIndex(findMe, colors, index);` is more what you want.

Comment: What is `NUM_COLORS`? No, it is not an `int *` that the third parameter to `findColorIndex()` must be, hence the compilation error.

Comment: You should include the actual, entire error message you are asking about.  I suspect your error is telling you that `NUM_COLORS` is **not** an array.  Do you agree that `NUM_COLORS` is not an array?

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to type this:

```
findColorIndex(findMe, colors, index);
```

Instead of passing NUM_COLORS, which is an int, not an int array.

Comment: Ok so this is helpful. That’s where my commented out idkWhy variable came in lol. It didn’t work either but i think i get the passing and int vs an int array thing now.

Comment: I noticed in your function you are not incrementing the index pointer being used to find the color, so perhaps you might want to try that as well. ```            functionIndex++;
            index++;``` HTH